# Neo4j c# toInteger cypher

Tags: c#, neo4jclient

I have a database that stores client's tickets bought. It stores the quantity of tickets sold in each relationship, I need to display the events ordered by the quantity in each relationship. The problem is that said quantity is stored as an integer, researching i found the `toInteger()` function that converts the strings into integers and then I get the ordered list. But when I try to implement said cypher in my C# application I cannot find a way to use `toInteger()`.

**Neo4j Cypher (that works correctly)**

```
MATCH(Cliente)-[r:Compro]->(b) return b.nombreEvento order by toInteger(r.cantidad) desc limit 5
```

**C# Cypher Try**

```
graphClient.Cypher
            .Match("(Cliente) -[r: Compro]->(b)")
            .Return(b => b.As<Cine>().nombreEvento)
            .OrderByDescending("r.cantidad")
            .Limit(5)
            .Results.ToList();
```

I am using Neo4jClient package for C#.

Does anyone know if said function can be used in Neo4jClient? Or help me by pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add in the `.OrderByDescending()` the `toInteger()` function like a string.

For example:

```
order by toInteger(r.cantidad) desc
```

would become:

```
.OrderByDescending("toInteger(r.cantidad)")
```